# Residue of $z^4e^\frac{1}{z-1}$ at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm interested in the residue of $z^4e^\frac{1}{z-1}$ at $z=1$
Following the Laurent expansion, I believe I get: 
$$
z^4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^n
 = z^4\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1} +\frac{1}{2!(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{3!(z-1)^3}...\right)
$$
I have been told through lectures to find the $z^{-1}$ term, however, in this case, I'm not too sure how to proceed

Comment: Think of it as residue of $(w+1)^4 e^{\frac{1}{w}}$ at $w=0$ and expand $(w+1)^4$.

Comment: Ah ok I think I follow you, just quickly ran through it all the way you said and it ended simplifying too $\frac{167}{40}$ as the residue. Had the one side as the expansion of $(w+1)^4$ and the other as the usual $1+\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{2!w^2}...$ multiplying them together to get the $z^{-1}$ term

Comment: You're missing a factor $z^4$ on the left.

Comment: Oh I did thanks for noticing I'll add that too the Laurent expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $z^4=(1+z-1)^4=1+4(z-1)+6(z-1)^2+4(z-1)^3+(z-1)^4$.  Multiplying, we get $1/5!+1/3!+1+2+1=501/120=167/40$ as the residue.